# How can I disable TrackFileAccess via CMake?

Tags: cmake, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

My company uses CMake to manage their code. Some of my colleagues are on Linux, and I'm on Windows, using Visual Studio. Our code is organised into a number of libraries, which translates into a number of Visual Studio projects under one solution.

To speed up compilation, I'm trying to integrate clcache with my setup. To do this, I need to disable `TrackFileAccess` for every project in the solution [as noted here](https://github.com/frerich/clcache/wiki/Caveats).

So, to my understanding, I have to modify the CMake files to either either inject some XML into each library's .vcproj file, or to modify the parameters passed to msbuild.exe itself. I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to do either of these things.

To try invoking msbuild.exe with specific command line parameters, I found the variable [CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM.html). I tried using it with `SET(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM "${CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM} /p:TrackFileAccess=false" CACHE INTERNAL "")`, but I can see from Process Explorer that msbuild.exe was not getting invoked with that argument.

I couldn't work out how I'd go about injecting XML into the .vcproj files, or if it can even be done with CMake. Is there actually a way to do it? Or would I instead need to perhaps write a script to run after CMake runs, to edit its output?

While we're at it, do I really need to edit every single .vcproj file, or could I perhaps edit something that each .vcproj will inherit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha!

I did more digging, and I think I'm barking up the wrong tree with CMake. It turns out, I could edit C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user.props and add in

```
<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <TrackFileAccess>false</TrackFileAccess>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and it works!

Comment: Sure. I was waiting to see if anyone came up with anything better.

Answer (score 0):

```
set(CMAKE_VS_GLOBALS "TrackFileAccess=false")
```